# How to build doxygen documentation in in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, documentation, doxygen, build.gradle

I'm using **Gradle** in Android Studio. And I would like to make documentation via **Doxygen** by *org.ysb33r.gradle.doxygen.Doxygen*.

At this moment I have this in **build.gradle** file:

```
   import org.ysb33r.gradle.doxygen.Doxygen

    // (...)

    doxygen {
        generate_html       true
        source              new File(projectDir,'src/main/headers')
        exclude             'build/'
        template            'template'
        outputDir           new File(projectDir,'docs/dox')
        html_header         new File(projectDir,'templete/header.html')
        html_footer         new File(projectDir,'templete/footer.html')
        html_stylesheet     new File(projectDir,'templete/customdoxygen.css')
        project_logo        new File(projectDir, 'template/finanteq_logo_doc.png')
        html_extra_files    new File(projectDir, 'template/favicon.ico')
        file_paterns        '*.java', '*.class','*.md'
        recursive           true
        exclude_paterns     '**/R.java', 'androidTest', '**/Test*.java'
    }

    //(...)

    task doxygenTask (type: Doxygen) {
        generate_latex true
        generate_html  true
    }
```

What can I do next?

Comment: Probably I have problem in set source.
[Doxygen documentation](https://github.com/ysb33r/doxygen-gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Example **build.gradle**:

```
doxygen  {
    generate_latex          true
    generate_html           true
    source                  projectDir
    include '*.java'
    include '**/*.md'
    use_mdfile_as_mainpage  new File(projectDir, 'readme.md')
    full_path_names         false

    //Project related configuration options
    project_logo            new File(projectDir,'logo.png')
    project_name            'Android'
    outputDir               new File(projectDir, 'docs/')
    optimize_output_java    true
    markdown_support        true
    autolink_support        true
    subgrouping             true

    //Configuration options related to the input files
    input_encoding          'UTF-8'
    file_paterns            '*.java','*.md'
    recursive               true

    //Configuration options related to source browsing
    strip_code_comments     true
    references_link_source  true
    source_tooltips         true
    verbatim_headers        true

    //Configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
    alphabetical_index      true
    cols_in_alpha_index     5

    //Configuration options related to the HTML output
    html_header             new File(projectDir,'header.html')
    html_footer             new File(projectDir,'footer.html')
    html_stylesheet         new File(projectDir,'custom.css')
    html_extra_files        new File(projectDir,'favicon.ico')
    generate_treeview       true
```